# How to open multiple URLs with a single click on the page?

Tags: javascript, html, popup, ads

I have a code to open a link in a new tab once someone visits my website. It's like a popup that brings them to another website.

I want to change my code so that it opens multiple URLs instead of just one. Here's what I have now:

```
<script><!--loc can be any changed to your window-->
var loc = "https://google.com/";
window.onclick = function() {
   window.open(loc);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like the following to accomplish this:

```
<script>
 var locs = ['site1.com','site2.com','site3.com'] 
 window.onclick = function() {
  for (let i = 0; i < locs.length; i++) {
   window.open(locs[i])
  }
 }
</script>
```